# Digits not displayed in result of simple computation

Tags: output-formatting, precision-and-accuracy

Matlab:

```
>> format long g
>> A=29357.71
A =

                  29357.71
>> B=7623.52
B =
                   7623.52
>> A+B
ans =
                  36981.23
```

I got what I entered. I entered `.71` in first input and Matlab doesn't ignore human orders (second law of robotics).

Mathematica:

```
A = 29357.71
29357.7
B = 7623.52
7623.52
A + B
36981.2
```

In first line it violates second order of robotics: human has entered `.71`, but Mathmatica think it doesn't matter by it's own reasons.

Is it possible to force Mathematica behave like normal calculator or like Matlab with command `format long g`?

Using suffix is either insufficient:

```
A = 29357.71`7
29357.71
B = 7623.52
7623.52
A + B
36981.2
```

or redundant

```
A = 29357.71`7
29357.71
B = 7623.52`7
7623.520
A + B
36981.23
```

Comment: Please look up `Accuracy` in the docs.

Comment: Mathematica shows only a limited number of digits, but the other digits _are_ there.

Answer (score 7):

To get close to Matlab's `format long g` you can try adding at top of your notebook

```
 $PrePrint = If[NumericQ[#], NumberForm[#, 15]] &;
```

Now

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

It worked the following way

```
A = 29357.71``3
29357.71
B = 7623.52``3
7623.52
A + B
36981.23
```

althoug I don't understand why should I enter `3` but not `2`.

Comment: That's probably not what you want. ``"Precision[29357.71``3]"`` returns `7.46772` which means less than eight digits of precision, while ``"Precision[29357.71`]"`` returns `MachinePrecision` which is double precision (the precision used by Matlab).